# RadioButtonFor, EditorFor, xxxFor on Property passed into Partials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Many of the properties on my model need to be represented a simple group of Yes/No radio buttons.  I need to check the corresponding radio button for pre-entered values.  I went with a partial.  Here's what I did:

**RadioButtonsYesNo.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<KeyValuePair<string,string>>" %>
<div id="<%:Model.Key %>">
<%: Html.ValidationMessage(Model.Key)%>
<ul class='RadioButtonsYesNo'><li>
<%: Html.RadioButton(Model.Key, "Yes", Model.Value == "Yes", new { id = Model.Key + "_Yes" })%>
<label for='<%: Model.Key %>_Yes'>Yes</label>
</li><li>
<%: Html.RadioButton(Model.Key, "No", Model.Value == "No", new { id = Model.Key + "_No" })%>
<label for='<%: Model.Key %>_No'>No</label>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

**Usage**

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("RadioButtonsYesNo", new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("MyProp",Model.MyProp)); %>
```

Is there a best practice for passing in the property of interest and having RadioButtonFor render correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or in Razor:

```
@{
    var yesRadioName = Model.Key + "_Yes";
    var noRadioName = Model.Key + "_No";

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Key, true, new { @id = yesRadioName })
    @Html.Label(yesRadioName , "Yes")
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Key, false, new { @id = noRadioName })
    @Html.Label(noRadioName, "No")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `RadioButtonFor` in an editor template:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<% string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(""); %>
<div id="<%: name %>">
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x) %>
    <ul class="RadioButtonsYesNo">
        <li>
            <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "Yes", new { id = name + "_Yes" }) %>
            <label for="<%: name %>_Yes">Yes</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, "No", new { id = name + "_No" }) %>
            <label for="<%: name %>_No">No</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyProp) %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The use of ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") seems rather convoluted, but this is .NET after all ;)